# Using gen_validatorv4.js to validate items in an array with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, validation

I'm working on a form that uses javascript-coder's gen_validatorv4 script. (Have used it in the past to great success). This form is so that tellers at the bank I work at can put information in on voided checks, to send back to our accounting department and get kicked out as a csv for Foxtrot.

I have tested the script in Firefox and Chrome, with no problems. However, in IE 8 and 9, I get the message "Line #1: Your account Number must be a number!", which is a validation error for not putting a number in that line, and as far as I can figure, it's because I'm using an array. It will repeat again with an error when attempting to do it under maxlen as well. I'm using the array (which is created by the previous form) as there is a variable set of number of checks which may be submitted at any given time.

Anyone have any ideas how to make it work in Internet Explorer properly?

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/syran/xL2EB/10/
I added the array-0.9.js file from js-methods, and that has slightly fixed the issue. It now properly validates the first line of items up to the radio button, but fails at that point. If I remove the radio button check, it will then fail on the 2nd row on num and maxlen verification. Please check the fiddle for the updated code, and an added second line.

HTML Code:

```
<form name="checkvoid" method="post">
<table id="mytable" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>Branch Number:
                <input type="text" name="bid" value="1" size="3">
            </td>
            <td colspan="6">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Voided Checks">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Date</td>
            <td align="center">Account #</td>
            <td align="center">Serial #</td>
            <td align="center">Amount</td>
            <td>MO</td>
            <td>CC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="check">
            <td>
                <select name="1[date][month]">
                    <option value="1">Jan</option>
                    <option value="2">Feb</option>
                    <option value="3">Mar</option>
                    <option value="4" selected>Apr</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">Jun</option>
                    <option value="7">Jul</option>
                    <option value="8">Aug</option>
                    <option value="9">Sep</option>
                    <option value="10">Oct</option>
                    <option value="11">Nov</option>
                    <option value="12">Dec</option>
                </select>
                <select name="1[date][day]">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29" selected>29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
                <select name="1[date][year]">
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2013" selected>2013</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="1[actnum]" size="10" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="1[serial]" size="10" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>$
                <input type="text" name="1[amount]" size="10" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="1[type]" value="1" CHECKED>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="1[type]" value="2">
            </td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="certify" value="1">I certify that all the information above is correct.</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="process">
```

Javascript:

```
var frmvalidator = new Validator("checkvoid");
frmvalidator.addValidation("bid", "req", "Please enter your Branch Number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("bid", "num", "Your Branch Number should be a Number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[actnum]", "req", "Line #1: You must enter an account number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[actnum]", "num", "Line #1: Your Account Number must be a number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[actnum]", "maxlen=8", "Line #1: Your Account Number cannot exceed 8 numbers!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[serial]", "req", "Line #1: You must enter a serial number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[serial]", "num", "Line #1: Your Serial Number must be a number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[serial]", "maxlen=10", "Line #1: Your Serial Number cannot exceed 10 numbers!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[amount]", "req", "Line #1: You must enter an amount!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[amount]", "num", "Line #1: Your Amount must be a number!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("1[type]", "selone", "Line #1: You must select either Money Order or Cashier's Check!");
frmvalidator.addValidation("certify", "shouldselchk", "Your must certify that the form is correct!");
```

I have it working without using an array in IE:  http://jsfiddle.net/syran/xL2EB/4/

Comment: js-methods helped with some of it, but still having issues with validating the array.

Answer (score 1):

Worked fine after I removed the `[]` brackets that you have wrapping your name property value.

`<input type="text" name="1[actnum]" size="10" value="1">` to `<input type="text" name="1actnum" size="10" value="1">`

You obviously have to update your js to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was caused by using a number as the datatype. IE didn't know how to handle it. Someone else gave me that tidbit, and I was able to fix it by creating a 2D array.

http://jsfiddle.net/syran/xL2EB/12/

```
 stuff[#][fieldname]
 frmvalidator.addValidation("stuff[1][actnum]", "req", "Line #1: You must enter an account number!");
```

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem and i change the add_validation function .
you can replace the add_validation function in gen_validatorv4.js to this :

```js
function add_validation(itemname, descriptor, errstr)
{
    var condition = null;
    if (arguments.length > 3)
    {
        condition = arguments[3];
    }
    if (!this.formobj)
    {
        alert("Error: The form object is not set properly");
        return;
    }


   var itemobj = this.formobj[itemname];


     var i=0;
     for (var key in itemobj)
     {
        i=parseInt(i)+1;
        var errtmp="";
        if(typeof(itemobj[key]) !="object" || itemobj[key]==null || itemobj[key].name==null  ) continue;

        if(itemobj[key].name.toString().indexOf("[]") >1 )
        {
              if (itemobj[key].length && isNaN(itemobj[key].selectedIndex))
             //for radio button; don't do for 'select' item
             {
                // itemobj[key] = itemobj[key][0];
             }
             if (!itemobj[key])
             {
                 alert("Error: Couldnot get the input object named: " + itemname);
                 return;
             }
             if (true == this.validate_on_killfocus)
             {
                 itemobj[key].onblur = handle_item_on_killfocus;
             }
             if (!itemobj[key].validationset)
             {
                 itemobj[key].validationset = new ValidationSet(itemobj[key], this.show_errors_together);
             }
             if(typeof(itemobj[key].validationset.add)=="function")
             {

                var errtmp=errstr.replace("{num}",i) ;
                 itemobj[key].validationset.add(descriptor, errtmp, condition);
                itemobj[key].validatorobj = this;
             }

        }
        else
        {
          var itemobj = this.formobj[itemname];

          if (itemobj.length && isNaN(itemobj.selectedIndex))
          //for radio button; don't do for 'select' item
          {
              itemobj = itemobj[0];
          }
          if (!itemobj)
          {
              alert("Error: Couldnot get the input object named: " + itemname);
              return;
          }
          if (true == this.validate_on_killfocus)
          {
              itemobj.onblur = handle_item_on_killfocus;
          }
          if (!itemobj.validationset)
          {
              itemobj.validationset = new ValidationSet(itemobj, this.show_errors_together);
          }
          itemobj.validationset.add(descriptor, errstr, condition);
          itemobj.validatorobj = this;
          break;
        }




    }

}
```